# How to add Json Model parameter in Langhcain?

Tags: python, debugging, openai-api, langchain

OpenAI recently released json object parameter for setting response_format to enable JSON mode. When JSON mode is enabled, the model is constrained to only generate strings that parse into valid JSON object.
Is there any way to add this in lagnchain ChatOpenAI ?

```py
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()

response = client.chat.completions.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo-1106",
  response_format={ "type": "json_object" },
  messages=[
    {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant designed to output JSON."},
    {"role": "user", "content": "How many Olympic medals have Usain Bolt have and from which games?"}
  ]
```

I have tried to send it in metadata,

```py
ChatOpenAI(openai_api_key=OPENAI_KEY , temperature=temperature, model=model, metadata={"response_format": { "type": "json_object" }})
```

But i don't know whether it worked or not.